# Why am I getting half of the job application form in German?

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I am from India and English is used everywhere in my profile. Why am I getting half of the job application form in German?

Job Posting URL - https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/306102/data-engineer-thoughtworks-inc

[image]

Comment: @NickCox This is a form directly on our site that we are responsible for maintaining. It is entirely relevant for it to be posted here.

Comment: Employers can configure custom job application fields. It seems like TW's German recruiters might have accidentally configured the custom fields for the Indian jobs. I'll see if we can get in touch with them.

Comment: Vote to close retracted. Thanks for explanations. Not the issue, but if questions in German asking you to chose a German city don't make sense, the job is not a good idea.

Comment: @Nick Not if it were a Stack Overflow Jobs UI bug...

Comment: A bug that inserts German city names rather than others would indeed be a problem.